# Can I ask Siri to connect an Apple TV to my AirPods?

Tags: bluetooth, appletv, siri, airpods

What is the correct command to get a 4th Generation Apple TV to connect to AirPods using Siri? When I try “connect to my AirPods”, all that happens is the Settings app opens and “Video and Audio” is selected. The AirPods are already paired to the Apple TV.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no command that you can use to get Siri to do that (at least not consistently).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to use Siri to connect your AirPods to your Apple TV: not listed on Apple’s [“Use Siri on your Apple TV” article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205300).

The fastest ways I’ve found are to swipe down from the top and select them in audio settings (for apps that support it) or hold the Play/Pause button when in the “menu”/“TV” view, to see your Bluetooth output options.